# docker wordpress and nginx user permission

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx

Trying to setup wordpress and nginx in docker containers while sharing the volume from wordpress to nginx. While doing so, nginx is unable to read the files from the volume as the users are different. How do I solve this?

This is currently causing this error below:

```
wordpress_1           | 172.18.0.17 -  18/Feb/2018:15:39:27 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
nginx_1       | 2018/02/18 15:39:27 [error] 7#7: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: galaxycard.in, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.18.0.13:9000", host: "127.0.0.1:3000"
nginx_1       | 172.18.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2018:15:39:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 47 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
```